# TypeError: pathname.charAt is not a function when passing an objet to "to" attribute in "Link"

Tags: react-router

Can someone tell me why I am having this error when I try to do following :

```
<Link
  activeClassName="active"
  to={{
     pathname: '/test',
     query: universalSearch !== '' ? {'search[text_search]': universalSearch} : {}
  }}
>
  {msg.app.menu.test}
</Link>
```

Comment: Which version or react-router are you using? Per the guides, the `to` prop can only take strings, query should be passed to the `query` prop.

Comment: I use 1.0.3 and I found this syntax there :

https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/68fdc826f6688e05d436add207cf296c8f5def6d/examples/query-params/app.js

I tried that because I loose active class when query is not empty. I though it could fix that...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attempting to use the 2.x RC syntax against the current 1.0.x release. The documentation on `master` matches the code on `master`, not the current release.

Please follow the documentation relevant to your release. See https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v1.0.3/docs/API.md#link or https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/v1.0.3/examples/query-params/app.js#L31.

Comment: Ok thank you! My bad! I am still stucked with activeClassName not being added when a query parameter is set...